# How to pass two parameter arguments int and double so that the invoke method can work?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a question on reflection in c sharp. This is my question

1) define class `MyClass` with different fields with different accessors(private, public, protected) also methods with different argument set and return types

2) define `MyTestClass` which contains method, that do the following: print method names for spicified class name, where methods contain string arguments, class name is string value. Call some method of class, and put arguments to method, arguments should read from text file(name of class and name of method is arguments of method

I want to invoke method5 in my class but it takes two parameters and when I try to I'm getting a mismatch count parameter error, how can I pass two parameters `int` and `double` so that the invoke method works?

```
Inside params.txt there is

10 1.5
```

and I want to read from a text file, this below is my full code any ideas or modification I will appreciate

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

class MyClass
{
    private int i;
    public double d;
    private string s;
    public bool b;
    public MyClass()
    {
        i = 1;
        d = 0.1;
        s = "1";
        b = true;
    }
    public void Method0()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method with no arguments, no return value.");
    }
    private int Method1(int arg0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The method returns int, int gets.");
        return arg0;
    }
    private double Method2(int arg0, double arg1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method returns a double, taking int and double.");
        return arg1 * arg0;
    }
    public bool Method3(string arg0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method returns a bool, accepts string");
        return arg0.Length>10;
    }
    public bool Method3(string arg0,string arg1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The method takes two arguments string.");
        return arg0 == arg1;
    }
    public static char Method4(string arg0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method returns a char, accepts string. .");
        Console.WriteLine(arg0);
        return arg0[1];
    }
    public void Method5(int arg0, double arg1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("arg1 = {0} arg2 = {1}.",arg0,arg1);
    }
}

class MyTestClass
{
    public static string[] GetMethodsWithStrParams(string className)
    {
        var t = Type.GetType(className);
        List<string> res = new List<string>();
        foreach (var method in t.GetMethods())
        {
            foreach (var param in method.GetParameters())
            {
                if (param.ParameterType == typeof(string))
                {
                    res.Add(method.Name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return res.ToArray();
    }
    public static void InvokeMethod(string className, string methodName, string fileName)
    {
        var t = Type.GetType(className);
        using (StreamReader f = new StreamReader("params.txt"))
        {
            t.GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[] { }),
                                           new object[] { f.ReadLine(), f.ReadLine()+"1" });
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = "MyClass";

        foreach (var x in MyTestClass.GetMethodsWithStrParams(name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

        MyTestClass.InvokeMethod("MyClass", "Method5", "params.txt");

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What was wrong with the answers given in the same question you asked earlier?

Comment: i can not fix it,im failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert all strings from the file to their respective types used in the method:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

class MyInvokedClass
{
  public void MyInvokedMethod(int arg0, double arg1)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("arg1 = {0} arg2 = {1}.", arg0, arg1);
  }
}

class Program
{
  public static void InvokeMethod(string className, string methodName, string fileName)
  {
    string[] contents = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    var t = Type.GetType(className);
    var m = t.GetMethod(methodName);

    var parametertypes = m.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType);

    var parameters = parametertypes.Select((type, index) => Convert.ChangeType(contents[index], type)).ToArray();
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    m.Invoke(instance, parameters);
  }

  static void Main()
  {
    InvokeMethod("MyInvokedClass", "MyInvokedMethod", "params.txt");

    Console.ReadKey(true);
  }
}
```

The file reads:

```
42
12.34
```

(note that you may have to replace the . by the decimal point used by your programs culture to work correctly)

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format is the error im getting

Comment: Did you put the file params.txt in your debug folder and did you change the double value to something that fits your culture? Because for me it works. Where do you get this exception? Which line?

Comment: yes i did the exception is coming from this line, var parameters = parametertypes.Select((type, index) => Convert.ChangeType(contents[index], type)).ToArray();

Comment: Then your culture probably uses something else for decimal points. Maybe you are from Germany and your double should look like this: `12,34` ?

Comment: it worked but im getting a parameter mismatch count exception on this codet.GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[] { }),
                                           new object[] { f.ReadLine()});

Comment: Well, you will need to figure out how to convert a string to a double on your system. Russia uses a comma as seperator, just as Germany.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a continuation of your previous question, here are a few problems that you need to solve:

1) I don't think that you want to have params.txt contain only arguments for `Method5`, otherwise your app will fail when you try another method

2) you need to parse the line from file into an array of objects.

I would do something like

params.txt:

```
Method5: 1 1.5
Method4: some string
...
```

I suggest using something like tab character as separator or a pipe (|) or anything you don't expect in valid arguments, otherwise you will not be able to have strings which contain spaces.

Now your code needs to find the line for the method being called and split it into parts to get the arguments. E.g. for `method5` you will now have 2 strings representing the arguments: "1" and "1.5"

Next thing you have to do is convert these strings into objects of correct type for that method call (i.e. int and double).

One approach is to encode the argument type into params.txt:

```
Method5L: 1:int 1.5:float
```

but this is error prone and it will easily go out of sync when you change your method, so better approach is to get the argument types via reflection, i.e. from `MethodInfo` object representing the method:

```
var parameters = method.GetParameters();
```

The last step is doing the conversion - you could use methods like `int.Parse`, `double.Parse` or even better, the `Convert` class, e.g.: `Convert.ChangeType("1.5", typeof(float))`

```
var args = new objects[parameters.Length]; 
var argStrings = {"1", "1.5"}; // obviously, you must get these from params.txt, not hardcode it
int idx = 0;
foreach (var param in parameters) {
    args[idx] = Convert.ChangeType(argStrings[idx], param.ParameterType);
    idx++;
}
```

Now you can provide the `args` array as parameter list to your method via `Invoke`.

There it is, now you just have to code it.

Comment: i should put it in the invoke method??ok im very confused

Comment: Yes, it should go into your `InvokeMethod` implementation, although there are better alternative designs which would take too much time to explain. I have explained what you need to do and possible problem with some alternatives. I have also added the code snippets for parts which might not be obvious. I can't go into details like where each line should be put, neither I can write all the code for you, but it shouldn't be that hard as all the parts are there, you just need to stitch them together.